# How to embed an image in a node with "mermaid.js"

Tags: javascript, html, mermaid

Is there any way to embed a picture with [mermaid.js](https://mermaidjs.github.io/) in a flow diagram graph node? I tried:

```
<div class="mermaid">
  graph LR
  A(<img src="pic.svg"></img>) --> B
</div>
```

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/1133#issuecomment-564036333

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the API example from [this thread](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/issues/548)

```js
var mermaidAPI = mermaid.mermaidAPI;

mermaidAPI.initialize({
  startOnLoad:false
});

var element = document.getElementById("app");
var insertSvg = function(svgCode, bindFunctions) {
  element.innerHTML = svgCode;
};
var graphDefinition = `graph LR; Systemstart-->SomeIcon(<img src='https://iconscout.com/ms-icon-310x310.png' width='40' height='40' />)`;
var graph = mermaidAPI.render("mermaid", graphDefinition, insertSvg);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8.0.0-rc.8/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hello , Can we add this image icon on the link ? rather than text?

Comment: but what I Have the image locally a can't upload it? It have to be shipped with .md file.

Answer (score 11):

[Example without Javascript:](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNpVkE1rwzAMhv-K8CUbNE3HdgprYU26XgYbrLekB2OrselsB1uhK0n--5x2g04geHn16AP1TDiJLGeN562CXVlbiPFSFcrrQIaHPaTpatgigXEWzwOs77YOgnJtq21zf-XXEwRF_zZhCKS0PY7XUnHpf7c4QFk9a9NA8GKZKKI25FmmhbNBuI7mwpnMhHQy0seHxXfMeWubBE5aklomT4sEFOpG0VVnq_3tht3JDbCp9IeKZ_6vKI9x-2t14PmBp4J7KLi_IGzGDHrDtYwv6CenZqTQYM3yKCX3x5rVdoxc10pOuJGanGdxzlfAGeMduc-zFSwn3-EfVGoe32l-qfEHKWdyDg)

```
graph TD
    A[Christmas] -->|Get money| B(Go shopping)
    B --> C{Let me think}
    C -->|One| D[<img src='https://iconscout.com/ms-icon-310x310.png' width='40' height='40' />]
    C -->|Two| E[iPhone]
    C -->|Three| F[fa:fa-car Car]
```

[image]

Comment: However, this is working only in the mermaid live editor. Any ideas on how can we use this approach in VS Code editor, Github readme, quarto, etc?

Comment: vscode - extention: `bierner.markdown-mermaid`

Comment: This isn't working

Comment: @AlexRamalho Works if wrapped with `<span style='min-width: 40px; display: block;'>...<span>`.  [Updated example](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNpVkF1rwjAUhv_KITfdwFrHvIpamNV5M9hg3rVeZElsgs0HSYoW639fWsfYDhw4vOc5n1dEDeMIo9oRK2C_qTREeykL4aQPivgDpGne73gAZTTvelg_7Ax4YayVun688-sBguL6NmAcgpD6dLunirH-XfMeNuXSW6LBh67hq0RJnZ4lCwLDfGYvC2DS24Z0GL4aQ0-LJF9KVYN3dJWIEKzHWSap0Z6aNkypUZny6SCkz0-zS_Sp1XUCY8tVMp8lILisRbjHWT4Ozw9_19qfTQ_bUn6IeNv_jHA8rvxaHgk-kpQSBwVxI4ImSHGniGTxb9dBqVAQXPEK4Rgy4k4VqvQtcqQN5rPTFOHgWj5BrWUk8I0k8d0KxcaN_1W3TAbjfsTbN8VThGo)